# How to add information about two same named databases on different hosts in PgBouncer config file?

Tags: postgresql, azure, psql, database-size, pgbouncer

I want to add details for databases in a config file of pgbouncer.
I have two same database names but their hosts are different, as there is no information about server endpoints in the config file, how will it get to know to which server it has to look for that database?
Can I have multiple connections on different port?
Like I want to use 6432 for pgsql1, 1234 for pgsql2 and they both are running simultaneously.
Will that work?

Answer (score 1):

Pgbouncer has [[databases]](https://www.pgbouncer.org/config.html#section-databases) section where you define names clients use to connect and the actual databases that mapped to these names. Assuming you have database db1 in 2 hosts, you will have something like

```
pgsql1 = host=host1.example.com port=5432 dbname=db1
pgsql2 = host=host2.example.com port=5432 dbname=db1
```

> Can I have multiple connections on different port?

pgbouncer process listens to one port defined by `listen_port` parameter. You  can have a setup where you run more than one pgbouncer on one machine with different configuration. I wouldn't recommend such setup though .